# Ensuring typescript can infer tuple type when mapping over an array literal

Tags: typescript

Given the following starting code:

```
type ComplexObjectType = {bar: (baz: number) => number}

const arr: [string, ComplexObjectType][] = [
    ['foo', {bar: baz => baz}]
]
```

If I immediately follow the array initialisation up with a `.map` like so:

```
const arr: [string, ComplexObjectType][] = [
    ['foo', {bar: baz => baz}]
].map(e => e)
```

Typescript will infer that `e` is of type `string | ComplexObjectType`. This makes sense because technically the array literal is untyped when this map happens.

All the following ways give errors since it is still inferring `e` to be `string | ComplexObjectType`:

**Attempt 1**

```
const arr: [string, ComplexObjectType][] = [
    ['foo', {bar: baz => baz}]
].map<[string, ComplexObjectType]>((e) => e)
```

**Attempt 2**

```
const arr: [string, ComplexObjectType][] = [
    ['foo', {bar: baz => baz}]
].map((e:[string, ComplexObjectType]) => e)
```

**Attempt 3**

```
const arr: [string, ComplexObjectType][] = [
    ['foo', {bar: baz => baz}]
].map((e) => e as [string, ComplexObjectType])
```

The only way I have found to get this working is to use an `as` on the array literal, like so:

```
const arr: [string, ComplexObjectType][] = ([
    ['foo', {bar: baz => baz}]
] as [string, ComplexObjectType][]).map((e) => e)
```

This duplication of the array type feels a little messy, and I was wondering if there was a neater way for typescript to infer the correct type here.

I would even prefer a way to modify the `map`'s function's types so an inference could be made.

Does anyone have any insight into why the attempts I made were not enough for typescript to infer the correct types?

Comment: It doesn't work because TS's typings for `map()` has a non-tuple array return type.  This could be altered to produce tuples when the input is a tuple, but it would only be able to handle homogeneous tuples, not heterogeneous tuples like `[string, ComplexType]`.  Mapping heterogeneous tuples would require that TS could identify a single callback like `e => e` and apply it to each element separately, and that would require higher kinded types which TS doesn't have.  See the linked questions and answers for more information.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. Possibly naive since type systems are fairly new to me, but if `map` has a non-tuple array return type, why does the last example where I explicitly cast the array literal work? In that case, typescript is correctly inferring the type of `e` to be a tuple and the return type of `map` to be an array of tuples.

Comment: That's a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (the term "cast" is ambiguous and best avoided in TS).  You're *asserting* the type to the compiler; it doesn't *infer* anything.  Compiler: "I think this is a `Array<string | ComplexObjectType>`.  You: "I assert that it is a `[string, ComplexObjectType]`".  Compiler: "oh, okay, I'll take your word for it."